# vbnet multiple combobox fill with one dataset

Tags: vb.net, combobox, dataset

i have the following code to fill two comboboxes using one dataset:

```
Private Sub sub_cbo_type_load()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds = cls.cbo_type()
    If ds IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso ds.Tables.Count > 0 _
    AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Me.r_cbo_type.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Me.r_cbo_type.DisplayMember = "desc"
        Me.r_cbo_type.ValueMember = "code"
        Me.r_cbo_type.SelectedIndex = -1
        Me.m_cbo_type.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Me.m_cbo_type.DisplayMember = "desc"
        Me.m_cbo_type.ValueMember = "code"
        Me.m_cbo_type.SelectedIndex = -1
    End If
End Sub
```

the problems is: whenever the index is changed in one combobox, it's automatically changed in the other one too.

does anyone know how can i solve this?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cloning the tables:

```
Private Function CopyTable(ByVal sourceTable As DataTable) As DataTable
  Dim newTable As DataTable = sourceTable.Clone
  For Each row As DataRow In sourceTable.Rows
    newTable.ImportRow(row)
  Next
  Return newTable
End Function
```

Then your data sources would be referencing different sources:

```
Me.r_cbo_type.DataSource = CopyTable(ds.Tables(0))

Me.m_cbo_type.DataSource = CopyTable(ds.Tables(0))
```

Answer (score -1):

do like this

```
 Private Sub btn_update1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_update1.Click
        If MsgBox("Are you sure to update?" & "", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirmation") = MsgBoxResult.Yes = True Then
            Dim transmode As String = vbNullString
            Dim byair As String = vbNullString
            Dim bysea As String = vbNullString
            If rb_air.Checked = True Then
                transmode = "A"
                byair = txt_mserial.Text '.Substring(txt_mserial.TextLength - 4, 4)
                bysea = vbNullString
            ElseIf rb_sea.Checked = True Then
                transmode = "B"
                byair = vbNullString
                bysea = txt_mserial.Text '.Substring(txt_mserial.TextLength - 4, 4)
            End If
            Try
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
                global_command = New SqlCommand("update ytmi_finished_products set rev_ctrl_no = '" & txt_mrev.Text & "', by_air = '" & byair & "', by_sea = '" & bysea & "', transport_mode = '" & transmode & "' where REPLACE(prod_no, '-', '') +'-'+ ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), prod_sx), '') + prod_lvl = '" & txt_mpart.Text & "' and cast(serial_no as numeric) = '" & txt_mserial.Text & "' and req_box_qty = '" & txt_mqty.Text & "' and remarks is null", con)
                global_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                global_command.Dispose()

                MsgBox("Successfully Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
                mclear()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Trace No 20: System Error or Data Error!" + Chr(13) + ex.Message + Chr(13) + "Please Contact Your System Administrator!", vbInformation, "Message")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```